# Is there Clojurescript library to replace jQueryUI Sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui, clojure, clojurescript

What it says in the title. I have a simple app that needs the functionality, but can be otherwise written in plain clojurescript so it seems pretty wasteful to load jQuery and jQueryUI just for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to jQueryUI's Sortable in the google closure library is [goog.fx.DragListGroup](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_fx_DragListGroup.html). As far as I know there is no ClojureScript wrapper for that, but it should be fairly simple to code against it directly and since it's in the closure library it should optimize well too. The basic idea is that you instantiate a `DragListGroup` for each independent list that you want to be sortable, and then add the list element to that group using `addDragList`. You can also add multiple list elements to the same group if you want to be able to drag elements between lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to get this working.  You'll need to use an extern file so Google Closure can read the jQuery libraries.  There is one for the main jQuery [already published](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git/contrib/externs) and I posted one that works well [for jQuery-ui's sortable](http://pastebin.com/cJYPtsmw).  The project.clj should have a reference to the extern, so include something like this:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
              [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1806"]
              [jayq "2.3.0"]]
:plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.1"]]
:cljsbuild {
          :builds [
                     {:source-paths ["src"]
                      :compiler
                      {:output-to "resources/public/js/out.js"
                       :optimizations :advanced
                       :pretty-print false
                       :externs ["resources/public/externs"]}}]})
```

Then write some cljs for the sortable function (jayq makes this easy):

```
(ns sortable.core
  (:use [jayq.core :only [$]]))

(defn sortable [$elem]
  (.sortable $elem))

(defn disable-selection [$elem]
  (.disableSelection $elem))

(let [$sortable ($ :#sortable)]
 (sortable $sortable)
 (disable-selection $sortable))
```

And include an index.html file for the project [like this](http://pastebin.com/fidSLYeX).

There might be some way to compile the jQuery libraries directly with :foreign-libs in the project.clj but I'm not sure how to do that.

EDIT: Sorry this still uses the entire jQuery library so it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have no clue about clojurescript I can't give you a proper solution in clojurescript but jQuery and jQuery UI shouldn't be that wasteful.

You could include the jQuery library by making use of the [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). Lots of websites use this source and therefore the file gets cached and won't be downloaded again and again.
See [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) link.

```
//you can of course easily change the version you want to use, like 1.9.1
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script
```

The [same](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui) could be done for jQuery UI

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But if you just want to use the `sortable` widget of jQuery UI you could simply use their [Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/).
Just uncheck the "Toggle all" checkbox below "Components" and then check the sortable checkbox in "Interactions".
Download your customized jQuery UI version and all you need to include is the `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` file. The Download Builder downloads a `CSS` theme also but for the sortable widget I see no need to include it.

But in fact including jQuery UI from Google CDN is also a good choice. If you host the libraries locally your users must download it at least once. If you use Google most of the user won't need to download the files. (unless the version is different)

Just a suggestion if there's nothing in clojurescript which could help you out.